# Load thumbnail image on failure response from uri - React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I need to render image tag in a loop based on array length,
My image tag looks similar to this

```
<Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og1.png'}}
//if image fails to load from the uri then load from'./img/favicon.png'
          onError={(error) => {console.log('loadinf',error)}}
        />
```

If error occurs while fetching from Uri i.e 404 error retry for sometime or show default local image.
How to do that in react native?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put in a loading image in the place of real image using `defaultSource` property but it is only available to iOS as of this moment. We can achieve the other thing you wrote that it should display a local image in case it couldn't load the image from the internet by the following approach.

1. Store the original image URI in state.
2. Use this URI from state in `source` of the image.
3. When `onError` function is called change this state variable to your local image.

Example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

export default class Demo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      image: {
        uri: 'something demo'
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <View>
        <Image
            source={ this.state.image }
            onError={(a) => {
                this.setState({
                    image: require('image.png')
                });
            }}
            style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
        />
    </View>
  }
}
```

A dirty hack for retrying the image would be something like this:

```
let counter = 0;
export default class reactNativePange extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            image: {
                uri: 'something demo'
            },
            failed: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Image
                  source={ this.state.failed ? require('./image.png') : { uri: 'something demo' } }
                  onError={(a) => {
                      if(counter >= 3) {
                          this.setState({
                              failed: true
                          });
                      } else {
                          counter++;
                          this.setState({
                              failed: true
                          });
                          setTimeout(() => {
                              this.setState({
                                  failed: false
                              });
                          }, 1)
                      }
                  }}
                  style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
              />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

> As I mentioned that this is a dirty hack as the image might flicker during the retry.

Comment: your answer will work for single image (1 image tag and 1 state variable ) but my scenario i have 1 state variable and the object is huge data(100 object in an array  and based on array count view will be rendered dynamically), i need to loop and update the object whether it's error or not. is there any easy way to achieve the same.

Comment: You can easily achieve this by making a component which will render this image. For ex. `CustomImage` can be a component and it can have a prop which will take in the URI and this above code can be adjusted into that component. This way you won't have to maintain 100 state variables manually. :)

Comment: thanks @Jagjot it works `export default class CustomImage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {imageFailed: false};
  }
  render() {
    return (
         <Image
           style={{height:100,width:100}}
           source={this.state.imageFailed ? require("./dummy-image.jpg") : {uri:this.props.imageuri}}
           onError={(error) => {this.setState({imageFailed : true})}}
           key={this.props.imageuri}
         />
    );
  }
}`
and is it possible to retry getting image from the same uri if error ? now iam showing default image.

Comment: is it possible to retry getting image from the same uri if error ?

Comment: Thank you.. i know its a dirty hack, but i just want to try for the scenario weather it will fullfil my requirement

Comment: @Aravindh I hope it works well for you. :) 
If this solves your problem then kindly mark this as the correct answer. Thanks!